# How to check if file or console is associated with Standard Output?

Tags: java

I am using following code to redirect standard out and standard error out to Log file depending on the boolean value of a variable.

```
if (logToFile==true){
java.io.File outputFile = new java.io.File(logFilePath);

System.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream(outputFile, true), true));
System.setErr(new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream(outputFile, true), true));

}
```

Moving further down my code, I want to find out whether my standard out and error out are associated with file - only then I would want to log few things. And over there, I don't have access to logToFile variable.

Is there any way to find out whether the standard out and error out are associated with file or the default console currently? And if they are associated to file then can we get the file path?

Comment: I really want to ask why you are doing it this way? There are many logging tools out there.

However :), to answer your question:

Do you know the format of what ERROR looks like?  Is it something that is specific like xyz.ERROR.xyz?  Because you can get take the first line of a file and see if it contains that.  Then you know it is the ERROR file, and the other one is the standard output.....but I really would like you to look into log4j if your project is a standalone for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364717/log4j-for-standalone-java-project

Comment: Also both files must have different names? Are you the one who sets the names? Do you know them before hand.  Maybe pass those file names as properties to your application, and then you can define which file to use....

Comment: @SusanMustafa - Why I am doing this way? Because we am using open source Talend  ETL where we are using Java for few adhoc things. It does not support Log4J out of the box as it is open source & not Licensed one.

Comment: @SusanMustafa - we are the one setting the file names. However, if we change the parameters of the called method and add filename while calling, then it will be long maintainence work for the many jobs that we have already developed.

Comment: You dont have to change any method parameters at all.

Create a application.properties file, and 
create a Java class which loads these Properties p = new Properties(); for you.   Inside your method you would then state if (shouldLog) {  System.setOut(........p.getProperty("output.file");   System.setError(.........p.getProperty("error.file");
}

Your application.properties file would contain:

output.file:projectRegularFile.log
error.file:projectErrorFile.log

I hope I am making sense?

https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Moving further down my code, I want to find out whether my standard out and error out are associated with file - only then I would want to log few things. And over there, I don't have access to logToFile variable.

What about storing the value of `logToFile` in a static variable, like for example:

```
if (logToFile) {
    StandardStreams.redirectToFile(new File(logFilePath));
}
```

```
public class StandardStreams {
    private static boolean redirectedToFile;

    public static void redirectToFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true), true);
        System.setOut(stream);
        System.setErr(stream);
        redirectedToFile = true;
    }

    public static boolean areRedirectedToFile() {
        return redirectedToFile;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
if (StandardStreams.areRedirectedToFile()) {
    // Log few things
}
```

---

> Is there any way to find out whether the standard out and error out are associated with file or the default console currently? And if they are associated to file then can we get the file path?

Create your own `PrintStream`:

```
class ConsoleLinkedFile extends PrintStream {
    private final File file;

    ConsoleLinkedFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(file, true), true);
        this.file = file;
    }

    File getFile() {
        return file;
    }
}
```

```
if (logToFile) {
    PrintStream stream = new ConsoleLinkedFile(new File(logFilePath));
    System.setOut(stream);
    System.setErr(stream);
}
```

To find out and retrieve the file path:

```
public static Optional<File> getFileIfRedirected(PrintStream stream) {
    if (stream instanceof ConsoleLinkedFile) {
        ConsoleLinkedFile linkedFile = (ConsoleLinkedFile) stream;
        return Optional.of(linkedFile.getFile());
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

```
if (getFileIfRedirected(System.out).isPresent()) {
    // Log few things
}
```

---

Note that the same `PrintStream` can be shared between standard input and standard error.

---

If you cannot create your own `PrintStream`, then you need to use reflection:

```
private static final VarHandle OUT, PATH;

static {
    final Class<?> OUT_class = FilterOutputStream.class;
    final Class<?> PATH_class = FileOutputStream.class;
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    try {
        OUT = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(OUT_class, lookup)
                .findVarHandle(OUT_class, "out", OutputStream.class);
        PATH = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(PATH_class, lookup)
                .findVarHandle(PATH_class, "path", String.class);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
}

private static Optional<String> getFileIfRedirected(PrintStream stream) {
    Object out = OUT.get(stream);
    if (out instanceof BufferedOutputStream) {
        out = OUT.get(out);
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable((String) PATH.get(out));
}
```

`VarHandle` is faster than `java.lang.reflect`. In Java 8, you can use the latter:

```
private static final Field OUT, PATH;

static {
    try {
        OUT = FilterOutputStream.class.getDeclaredField("out");
        OUT.setAccessible(true);
        PATH = FileOutputStream.class.getDeclaredField("path");
        PATH.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
}
```